# Android replace Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

My MainActivity contains 2 fragments. The upper one contains a map and should be visible all the time. The lower one should initially show a ListView and on FAB clicked it should change to a Fragment, in which it is possible to add a new entry.

[image]

I tried to run the following code in my MainActivity on button click:

```
    AddFragment newFragment = new AddFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

But nothing is happening at all.

Here is my XML:

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/frag_list"
            android:name="com.example.imissit.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you just change the `LinearLayout` to `FrameLayout`

Comment: Yep I did it. Now at least something is happening: Now the fragment is overlaying the first one

Comment: Which one, ListFragment?

Comment: The AddFragment is above the ListFragment

Comment: Yes, it will be over that one.

Comment: But shouldn't it remove the ListFragment?

Comment: No, because the fragment is added stastically.

Comment: As mbelsky suggested I also removed the fragment from the XML, seems to work now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `fragment` tag from xml file, and add the `ListFragment` programmatically, f.e.:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(…);
    if ( null == savedInstanceState ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(CONTAINER_ID, FRAGMENT_INSTANCE, TAG) // Change the values
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Also change `LinearLayout` to `FrameLayout`

Comment: @4ndro1d great. Please mark the answer as  solution.